# preloading short MP3 clips in Python to eliminate playback gaps (for use with an Alexa skill)

Tags: python, mp3, alexa-skills-kit

I've asked this question over in the Alexa forums and not really getting any traction.  I hope the general Python community might be able to help, and then I can see if it works in the Python Alexa skill environment.

I have short (1-3 second length) mp3 files hosted in an Amazon S3 bucket, and want to play them in my alexa skill.  I need to be able to mix the order of the effects depending upon what is happening in the skill but they need to sound like 1 long MP3 when played i.e. no silence/delay between the playing of each sample.  At the moment I get something like 0.5 to 1 second gap, and it is varaible.  Although small, this silence isn't acceptable for my skill application.

I'm currently using SSML and it was suggested that I use the Alexa audioplayer instead but, I have seen forum comments that this player also suffers from latency.

Effectivly, this is what my skill is doing:

```
speak_output =  '<speak> Here are some sounds'
if (a=b):
  speak_output += '<audio src="https://s3xxx/file/anEffect.mp3" />'
speak_output += '<audio src="https://s3xxx/file/anotherEffect.mp3" />'
speak_output += '<audio src="https://s3xxx/file/aThirdEffect.mp3" />'
speak_output +=  '</speak>'
        
print (speak_output)
        
return (
     handler_input.response_builder
         .speak(speak_output)
         .ask(speak_output)
         .response
```

Is there a python technique for preloading MP3 files, or combining multiple files into 1 "virtual" file before being played?  The effects I'm looking to play in 1 sequence will last no longer than around 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing... You're sending a TEXT response to Alexa with the audio URLs in it. The spec says they must be internet accessible and served via HTTPS. So you're not loading them in your skill handler. The Alexa service is loading them based on your response and then sending them to the device.

Audioplayer is not for mixing small clips like you want. You're supposed to support shuffle on/off, next/back, etc. when you use it. You're having to support a bunch of behaviors you don't want and you might have your skill rejected if you don't.

I tried getting around that with a Data URL in my SSML (converting the file to text and sending the file itself as the URL) as an experiment, but the service gave me an error. Even if it didn't, you'd quickly run up against the service limits of 8000 characters in a URL string and 24000 in the total response.

Have you thought about setting up a service which can take the sequence as a query, append them to each other in memory, and return the combined audio as a file? I'm not a Python person, but it seems you could do it with "reasonable" ease using PyDub.

Comment: Thanks @LetMyPeopleCode.  I'll investigate PyDub - I assume you mean run this as a service outside of the skill itself (possibly still in lambda) - the skill would send the required order of effects to the service and the service would respond with the URL link?  That could work.  What I also need to be mindful of is the compute time.  I don't want to be hit with lots of users (assuming the skill is used!) regularly hittting the lamda service and costing me losts of compute time per month.  That'll be another factor in my evaluation!  Thanks again.  I'll report back.

Comment: Yes, the service would run outside of the skill. Lambda is way cheaper than you may think. It'd likely take thousands of monthly users before such a service started costing as much as a Happy Meal.

The service would be the link (use API Gateway) and would return the combined sound as if you'd linked directly to an MP3, but it constructs the sound on the fly with PyDub. Depending on how many possible combos there are, you could also just use pyDub to pre-build the lot locally, store them on S3, and then just call the right combo from your skill.

Comment: Understood.  I can afford a happy meal - so I hope you're right :-).  Final query (!), I assume the lamda service would need to write the combined MP3 to S3 and send the link back to the skill?

Comment: No, you should be able to send the composed sound as a stream. Just make sure you're properly setting the MIME type in the HTTP response headers and it should seem no different than responding with a file to any consumer of the service.